# JSON nested and React JS

Tags: json, reactjs, web, nested

I am having touble accessing json nested data. How should I access package starting point and ending point? My code below is not working. Also how do I made the button redirect in such a way that on clicking it, it shows the rest of the package information of that shipment in a table form? I dont know how to link the button to a particular shipment. Ideas?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Navigation from './navigation';
import "./status.css";

export default function ViewStatusMenu (props) {

return (
  <div >
    <header  className="App-header">
      <h1 className="App-title2">Aid Tracker</h1>
      <Navigation/>
    </header>
    <div className="base">
      <h3> Shipments</h3>
      <ul className ="statusmenu">  {

        props.data.map(temp => {
           return (

             <div>

                <p>Shipment ID</p>
                <li className ="statuslist" temp={temp} key={temp.id}> {temp.id}</li>
                <p>Shipment name</p>
                <li className ="statuslist" temp={temp} key={temp.id}> {temp.name}</li>
                <p>No of packages</p>
                <li className ="statuslist" temp={temp} key={temp.id}> {temp.no_of_packs}</li>
                <p>Starting point</p>
                <li className ="statuslist" temp={temp} key={temp.id}> {temp.packages.starting_point}</li>
                <p>Starting point</p>
                <li className ="statuslist" temp={temp} key={temp.id}> {temp.packages.ending_point}</li>

                <button>View Shipment</button>

              </div>

            )
          }
        )
      }

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

}

JSON data

```
      [
        {
               "id": 112346,
               "name":"XYZ",
                "no_of_packs": "3",
                "packages":
                [

                { "rnd": 112346, "starting_point": "Point C", "point_2": "2/07/17", "point_3": "2/07/17","ending_point": "2/07/17","Delivery_date": "5/05/18"},
                { "rnd": 112346, "starting_point": "Point C", "point_2": "2/07/17", "point_3": "2/07/17","ending_point": "2/07/17","Delivery_date": "5/05/18"},
                { "rnd": 112346, "starting_point": "Point C", "point_2": "2/07/17", "point_3": "2/07/17","ending_point": "2/07/17","Delivery_date": "5/05/18"},
                { "rnd": 112346, "starting_point": "Point C", "point_2": "2/07/17", "point_3": "2/07/17","ending_point": "2/07/17","Delivery_date": "5/05/18"}

        ]
      },
      {
         "id": 112346,
         "name":"XYZ",
         "no_of_packs": "3",
         "packages":

          [

                        { "rnd": 112346, "starting_point": "Point C", "point_2": "2/07/17", "point_3": "2/07/17","ending_point": "2/07/17","Delivery_date": "5/05/18"},
                        { "rnd": 112346, "starting_point": "Point C", "point_2": "2/07/17", "point_3": "2/07/17","ending_point": "2/07/17","Delivery_date": "5/05/18"},
                        { "rnd": 112346, "starting_point": "Point C", "point_2": "2/07/17", "point_3": "2/07/17","ending_point": "2/07/17","Delivery_date": "5/05/18"},
                        { "rnd": 112346, "starting_point": "Point C", "point_2": "2/07/17", "point_3": "2/07/17","ending_point": "2/07/17","Delivery_date": "5/05/18"}

          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 112346,
          "name":"XYZ",
          "no_of_packs": "3",
          "packages":

          [

                        { "rnd": 112346, "starting_point": "Point C", "point_2": "2/07/17", "point_3": "2/07/17","ending_point": "2/07/17","Delivery_date": "5/05/18"},
                        { "rnd": 112346, "starting_point": "Point C", "point_2": "2/07/17", "point_3": "2/07/17","ending_point": "2/07/17","Delivery_date": "5/05/18"},
                        { "rnd": 112346, "starting_point": "Point C", "point_2": "2/07/17", "point_3": "2/07/17","ending_point": "2/07/17","Delivery_date": "5/05/18"},
                        { "rnd": 112346, "starting_point": "Point C", "point_2": "2/07/17", "point_3": "2/07/17","ending_point": "2/07/17","Delivery_date": "5/05/18"}

          ]
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should give you a clue
used your data , currently displaying only ID, but can show all the data.
for redirect you need to create another route & component to render a new page

```js
const data = [{
    "id": 112346,
    "name": "XYZ",
    "no_of_packs": "3",
    "packages": [

      {
        "rnd": 112346,
        "starting_point": "Point C",
        "point_2": "2/07/17",
        "point_3": "2/07/17",
        "ending_point": "2/07/17",
        "Delivery_date": "5/05/18"
      },
      {
        "rnd": 112346,
        "starting_point": "Point C",
        "point_2": "2/07/17",
        "point_3": "2/07/17",
        "ending_point": "2/07/17",
        "Delivery_date": "5/05/18"
      },
      {
        "rnd": 112346,
        "starting_point": "Point C",
        "point_2": "2/07/17",
        "point_3": "2/07/17",
        "ending_point": "2/07/17",
        "Delivery_date": "5/05/18"
      },
      {
        "rnd": 112346,
        "starting_point": "Point C",
        "point_2": "2/07/17",
        "point_3": "2/07/17",
        "ending_point": "2/07/17",
        "Delivery_date": "5/05/18"
      }

    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 112346,
    "name": "XYZ",
    "no_of_packs": "3",
    "packages":

      [

        {
          "rnd": 112346,
          "starting_point": "Point C",
          "point_2": "2/07/17",
          "point_3": "2/07/17",
          "ending_point": "2/07/17",
          "Delivery_date": "5/05/18"
        },
        {
          "rnd": 112346,
          "starting_point": "Point C",
          "point_2": "2/07/17",
          "point_3": "2/07/17",
          "ending_point": "2/07/17",
          "Delivery_date": "5/05/18"
        },
        {
          "rnd": 112346,
          "starting_point": "Point C",
          "point_2": "2/07/17",
          "point_3": "2/07/17",
          "ending_point": "2/07/17",
          "Delivery_date": "5/05/18"
        },
        {
          "rnd": 112346,
          "starting_point": "Point C",
          "point_2": "2/07/17",
          "point_3": "2/07/17",
          "ending_point": "2/07/17",
          "Delivery_date": "5/05/18"
        }

      ]
  },
  {
    "id": 112346,
    "name": "XYZ",
    "no_of_packs": "3",
    "packages":

      [

        {
          "rnd": 112346,
          "starting_point": "Point C",
          "point_2": "2/07/17",
          "point_3": "2/07/17",
          "ending_point": "2/07/17",
          "Delivery_date": "5/05/18"
        },
        {
          "rnd": 112346,
          "starting_point": "Point C",
          "point_2": "2/07/17",
          "point_3": "2/07/17",
          "ending_point": "2/07/17",
          "Delivery_date": "5/05/18"
        },
        {
          "rnd": 112346,
          "starting_point": "Point C",
          "point_2": "2/07/17",
          "point_3": "2/07/17",
          "ending_point": "2/07/17",
          "Delivery_date": "5/05/18"
        },
        {
          "rnd": 112346,
          "starting_point": "Point C",
          "point_2": "2/07/17",
          "point_3": "2/07/17",
          "ending_point": "2/07/17",
          "Delivery_date": "5/05/18"
        }

      ]
  }
];



class App extends React.Component {
  redirectToItem = (item) => {
    // your redirect code goes here
  };

  renderItem = (item, index) => < li onClick = {
      () => this.redirectToItem(item)
    } >
    <
    span > {
      item.id
    } < /span> <
    /li>;

  render() {
    return <div >
      <
      h3 > Shipments < /h3> <
      ul className = "statusmenu" > {
        data.map(this.renderItem)
      } <
      /ul> <
      /div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How exactly am I supposed to redirect and use item in that function? @Idan

Comment: redirect using history.push

Comment: This is my first time working on react. I don't know how to do that. Can you elaborate or share a link where I can learn about this? @Idan

Comment: I would just display it in the same page in that case.

Comment: Thanks for the link @Idal

Comment: you want to have the data displayed in the same page or you want to split the app to 2 pages ?

Comment: split it into two pages @Idal

Comment: https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf - you have to start by creating the routing & views

Comment: this is my index.js



ReactDOM.render(

  <Router>
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/"  exact strict component={App} />
        <Route  path="/vs" component={VisitStatus} />
        <Route path="/cs"  component={Create} />
        <Route path="/vsm"  component={ViewStatus} />


        </Switch >
    </div>
  </Router>,

  document.getElementById('root')
);

registerServiceWorker();

Comment: even if I redirect how exactly will I use item to display that specific shipment's information?? @Idan

Comment: you need to have your data on a shared place like, and both views can use it.

Comment: Both views can access the data.json file but how will this redirected view know which shipment to show out of all the shipments in that json file? @idal

Comment: when you redirect , do something like that : History.push("/vsm?id=3"); - on your ViewStatus component , you can find the id using:  qs.parse(this.props.location.search).id